# Exact formulation of the law of large numbers for i.i.d. Paretian variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems

If $X_1, X_2, ...$ are i.i.d. Pareto-distributed variables with parameter $\alpha$, I have read (in a heuristic source) that
$\frac{1}{n^{1/\alpha}} \sum_{k = 1}^n X_k$ fulfills some law of large numbers, or even a generalized central limit theorem.

Can anyone help me with the exact formulation (i.e. is it the weak or strong law?) or give me a mathematical source where I find this?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Ok, I found it in Kallenberg's "Foundations of Modern Probability".